# How to display the values count on the bar chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Can I please get some help on how I can include the counts on my bar chart. Thank you.

```
sns.countplot(data['target'])
plt.plot(0, label ="0 = No")
plt.plot(1, label ="1 = Yes")
plt.xlabel("Target")
plt.ylabel("count")
plt.title("Target vrs count")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.DataFrame({'target': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
sns.countplot(data.target);
for v in [0, 1]:
    plt.text(v, (data.target == v).sum(), str((data.target == v).sum()));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I get an error saying                 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-7bb18d7a02d9> in <module>()
     13 sns.countplot(data.target);
     14 for v in [0, 1]:
---> 15     text(v, (data.target == v).sum(), str((data.target == v).sum()));

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @KwesiGene You apparently have a module called `text`. Try using `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`, and then using `plt.text`.

Comment: sorry, but I tried it but still throwing an error saying text not available.  Link to the error:                                    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HPWbXLqisCpi5gu4h5wgqnHTdKPL_-Mp

Comment: @KwesiGene I updated the answer to show exactly what I meant.